# I suggest a closed badge

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, negative-badges

I suggest that a set of 'closed' badges be added.
Bronze for first question closed, silver for 10 questions closed, and perhaps a gold...

Comment: for having your own question closed, that is

Comment: What good behaviour is this supposed to encourage?

Comment: This is not supposed to encourage good behavior but discourage bad behavior. This is to warn that this person (in this case, yours truly) has had his questions closed, one too many times.

Comment: If there had been a 'rust' badge I would have suggested that...

Answer (score 15):

Badges are meant to encourage good behaviour. The only exception to this is the Tumbleweed badge which is a consolation prize.

The most common close reason is probably duplicate, having these badges would just discourage people from checking before posting.

"It doesn't matter if it's a duplicate, it's one more to my total, gold `Closed` badge here I come!"

Comment: @ChrisF: As I commented above, had there been a 'rust' badge I would have recommended that

Comment: @Yaneeve: I think @ChrisF is right.  It doesn't matter what color the badges are, people will try to collect them.

Comment: Well, I personally have specifically avoided the Peer Pressure badge. (Then again, I've only had one chance at it.)